# Saving and Reading doubles without precision loss

Tags: python, c, floating-point

I want to save a sequence of double into a .txt file, and read them later on in C. How can I achieve this without precision loss? What I don't know to do is how many digits I need to save? I doubt I may not get the exact double I saved if not enough digits are saved.

Below is what I have tried

```
doubles=[3.14159, 3.14159265358]
filename="tmp.txt"
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    for x  in doubles:
        f.write("%.16f\n" %x)
```

I got two (I guess) imprecise representation of my data, `doubles`. 
    3.1415899999999999
    3.1415926535800001

This is undesirable. I want data to be stored as is, so that another program can retrieve them exactly. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/7076153

Comment: (Python) floats have some limitations: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: You can save them as binary, however, then they are not necesarilly transportable to other machines with other architectures.

Comment: Why not do you store them as a fractions?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - Actually, you _can_ store floating point numbers in such a way as to preserve their precision.  But you have to put bounds on to how precise you need to be.  (and as I was typing this comment, Bathsheba's answer appeared).

Comment: You can `sprintf` them using the `%a` format as long as you don't mind them not being (average) human-readable! However, this is only supported by C, not Python.

Comment: @JoseFelipe - Fractions would work for storing only rational numbers.  What about irrationals?  eg. what fraction would you suggest for storing `PI`?

Comment: @ryyker good point, that was a stupid question of mine. Thank you.

Comment: To write, use exponential format, not `"f"`.  The C-ish answer is `"%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG ,x` or `"%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, x` or `"%a", x`

Comment: @ryyker Re: [What about irrationals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023663/saving-and-reading-doubles-without-precision-loss#comment89040494_51023663): All finite `double` are rational, so irrationals do not apply to "Saving and Reading doubles without precision loss".  Even the common `M_PI`, a close approximation of π, is rational

Comment: @JoseFelipe Storing the `double` as an exact  fraction is a reasonable approach that has some merits.

Answer (score 3):

From C11, use `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` which is defined *exactly* for this use: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits. It tells you the number of decimal digits of precision required such that a load of a saved `double`, followed by a save then a reload will mean that the two load steps will *always* return the same `double`.

`DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is normally 17.

Comment: `DBL_DIG` is insufficient. Use `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.

Comment: @chux: May as well remove the old `DBL_DIG` unless that's against C tag ettiquette: In C++ now we seem to have a consensus in accepting that C++11 is the default standard.

Comment: `DBL_DIG` remains useful.  It is the most digits that text-`double`-text can round-trip correctly for all `double`.  These 2 macros apply in different situations.

Comment: When `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is not available, code can use `DBL_DIG + 3` to derive the digits needed for `double`-text-`double` as in OP's case.  It might be a tad more than  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`, but never too small.